# My listview with database is not working

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi I have created a **list view in my activity**,in which I **want to display the contents from the database**. but an error occured saying there is **no list view found** Can anybody give me a better solution to overcome the error?

**my log cat is given below**

```
08-21 06:54:52.103: E/AndroidRuntime(6874): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 06:54:52.103: E/AndroidRuntime(6874): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.neochat/com.neochat.Friends}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.neochat/com.neochat.Friends_list}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
08-21 06:54:52.103: E/AndroidRuntime(6874):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-21 06:54:52.103: E/AndroidRuntime(6874):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-21 06:54:52.103: E/AndroidRuntime(6874):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
```

**I am giving my code for the listview java class below**

```
public class Friends_list extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener{

    private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    private String tableName = LoginDataBaseAdapter.tableName;

    private SQLiteDatabase newDB;

    ListView listview;
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        openAndQueryDatabase();

        displayResultList();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends);
        context=this;

        listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        //String[] arrayColumns=new String[]{"Name,Username"};
        //int[]arrayViewIDs=new int[]{R.id.textViewSMSSender,R.id.textViewMessageBody};
        Cursor cursor;


        //cursor.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),null,null,null,null);

        //@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        //SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.friendsms, cursor, arrayColumns, arrayViewIDs);
        //listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        // android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, android.R.id.text1,value);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    private void displayResultList() {

        TextView tView = new TextView(this);
        tView.setText("Friends");
    getListView().addHeaderView(tView);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }

    private void openAndQueryDatabase() {
        try {
            LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this.getApplicationContext());
            newDB=loginDataBaseAdapter.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor c=newDB.rawQuery("  SELECT    NAME   ,   USERNAME     FROM    "+ tableName, null);
            if (c != null ) { 
                if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String Name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
                        String Username=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("USERNAME"));
                    } while(c.moveToNext());                
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not open the database");
        } finally {
            if(newDB!=null)
                newDB.execSQL("   DELETE    FROM   "+ tableName);
            newDB.close();
        }
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Intent in2=new Intent(Friends_list.this,InboxActivity.class);
        startActivity(in2);
    }       
}
```

**Here is the code where I have created my database**

```
public class LoginDataBaseAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int NAME_COLUMN=2;
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserDetails.db";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    static final String tableName="Signup";
    static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "   
   + " Signup "+ " " + "  "
   + " ( "    
   + " ID "  
   + " integer primary key autoincrement , "   
   + " NAME text , USERNAME text , PASSWORD text , EMPLOYEE_CODE text," 
   + " MOBILE_NUMBER integer ); ";

    public SQLiteDatabase db;
    private final Context context;
    private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
```

here is my xml file which contains list view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="6dp"
    tools:context=".Friends" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </TabHost>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        style="@style/WhiteText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="43dp">
    </ListView>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: LogCat "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 

'android.R.id.list'" so post your xml

Comment: see updated code...above

Comment: it is working now thank you guys for help and sorry for getting out of touch...

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are calling displayResultList() function before your setContentView and after all before find the id of your ListView....

So change it with:

```
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends);


   listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    openAndQueryDatabase();
    displayResultList();}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have called `setContentView` inside your `onCreate` method. Your `R.layout.activity_friends` file contains a listview, but its id is `listView1`.

If you take a good look at the exception then you will see that android is expecting a listview whose id is `list`.

You can do one of the following things to resolve the exception

1. Change the id of listView in your xml from `listView1` to `list`
2. Since your activity extends from ListActivity, it inherits a ListView whose id is `android.R.id.list`. In that case simply comment the call to setContentView() method.
3. Extend from Activity and not ListActivity.

Please read android docs for ListActivity class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Comment: hey dude I have tried this now there is no error visible but my list view is not displaying..

Answer (score 0):

because you activity extends ListActivity , the ListActivity include a ListView ,you can get the ListView by Code  this.mListView = getListView();,you need not to setContentView()

Answer (score 0):

1、you should delete " setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends);"
2.mothed "findViewById()" should be insteaded by mothed getListView();